# What is the name of this old Arcade game?

Tags: game-identification

[image: Screenshot of unknown game]

It has been years and years since I saw this game and for the life of me I cannot remember what it was called...

Answer (score 16):

This screenshot is from a 1987 Capcom arcade game called [Black Tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Tiger_(video_game)).

Answer (score 8):

The game [Black Tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Tiger_%28video_game%29) was released in August of 1987 (for japan) and in an unspecified 1987 (for the US) and is a Hack and Slash plat-former game.

The gamer features a barbarian who jumps and fights his way through levels of spiraling colorful towers.

It was designed by [Imo Akapa](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5070389/), and he has not programmed any games since then. Not much is known about Imo Akapa.

The display is a vintage 256×224 pixels, with 1024 colors.

The **Game Flyer** for Black Tiger can be seen below:

[image]